# .NET Core, Running msbuild task after CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have at netcoreapp2.0 application with the following property set:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Right after it finishes copying the dependency DLL's to the output folder i want to run a msbuild-task that depends on those DLL's being in the folder.

I have tried the following, but it seems to run the command a step to early and the command does not see the DLL's.

```
<Target Name="SomeName" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="SomeCommand" />
</Target>
```

Tried to find a list of targets .NET Core supports, but to no avail, so i'm looking for a list of build targets or a target that i can trigger on after the dependency DLL's have been copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (public, non underscore-prefixed) target that you could use is [`CopyFilesToOutputDirectory`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/5bfa97df0c264d793539e81ed578fc0cb52b5557/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L4040):

```
<Target Name="MyProcessingStep" AfterTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
  …
</Target>
```